# Can't print out matches of regular expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code, and I want to print out all the names of the people who are vegan, currently it just prints "-".

```
var  people = `- james (vegan)
                     - David 
                     - Craig (vegetarian)
                     - Bob (vegan)`

    if (/[-\s(\w+?)\s(?=\(vegan\))]/.test(people) == true)
        {
            var match = /[-\s(\w+?)\s(?=\(vegan\))]/
            document.write(people.match(match))
        }
    else 
        {
            document.write("invalid")
        }
```

I've tried this aswell

```
console.log(people.match(match));
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Your whole regex is inside a character set. Take that out, for one

Comment: Okay, done, I've got /-\s([\w]+)\s(?=\(vegan\))/ now which prints out, "- james ,james"?

Comment: yes, because it `match`es - what did you expect?

Comment: I expected -james, -bob

Comment: then you'll need more than one match ... `g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is incorrectly written and just has one character set due to which it only matches one character at a time and prints that. You need to correct your regex with this JS Code,

```js
var  people = `- james (vegan)
                     - David 
                     - Craig (vegetarian)
                     - Bob (vegan)`

    if (/-\s+\w+(?=\s+\(vegan\))/.test(people) == true)
        {
            var match = /-\s+\w+(?=\s+\(vegan\))/
            console.log(people.match(match))
        }
    else 
        {
            console.log("invalid")
        }
```

In case you just want to print only the names of people that are vegan, you can use this code.

```js
var  people = `- james (vegan)
                     - David 
                     - Craig (vegetarian)
                     - Bob (vegan)`

    if (/-\s+\w+(?=\s+\(vegan\))/.test(people) == true)
        {
            var match = /-\s+(\w+)(?=\s+\(vegan\))/g;
            var m = match.exec(people);
            while (m!= null) {
                console.log(m[1]);
                m = match.exec(people);
            }
        }
    else 
        {
            console.log("invalid")
        }
```

**Edit:**
As per [Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s suggestion, you actually don't need to separately call `test` method and then `match/exec` which will be costly and instead you can use these codes, where need of `test` method is removed. Thanks to [Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) for following my answer and giving great suggestion.

Here is the updated JS code demo,

```js
var  people = `- james (vegan)
                     - David 
                     - Craig (vegetarian)
                     - Bob (vegan)`
                     
var match = /-\s+(\w+)(?=\s+\(vegan\))/g;
var m = match.exec(people);

if (m == null) {
 console.log("invalid")
} else {
        console.log(m[1]);
 while ((m = match.exec(people))!= null) {
  console.log(m[1]);
 }
}
```

Comment: You made two other chanegs ... why did you remove the `()` around `\w+` ? why did you add `g`?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Ah you're right. My mistake, for printing just name, that grouping will be needed. Let me update my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Very good regex ++ Though I think 2 separate calls to `test` and then `match` methods can be combined into one.

Comment: @anubhava: You're correct indeed. I just tried to make minimal changes in OP's code to make it work, but I think it will be better if I suggest even better codes like you suggested where he doesn't need to call `test` and `match` methods separately doubling the regex cost. Let me update your suggestion in my post. Thanks for your suggestion. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `/\s*-\s(.+?)\s\(vegan\)/`. Use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) like this:

```js
let regex = /\s*-\s(.+?)\s\(vegan\)/g, 
    matches = [], 
    match,
    str = `- james (vegan)
                     - David 
                     - Craig (vegetarian)
                     - Bob (vegan)`

while(match = regex.exec(str))
  matches.push(match[1])

console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
people.split('\n')
  .map(line=>line.trim())
  .map(line=>{
    let matched = line.match(/-\s(\w+)(\s\((\w+)\))?/); 
    return {name: matched[1],type:matched[3]};
  })
  .filter(item=>item.type=='vegan')
  .map(item=>item.name)
```